# How do I float my box in the center?

Tags: html, css, center, box

Ok, so I tried using the css element, float: center;. But, it won't work. Is there any other way to float my box in the center of my webpage. I'm talking horizontally center by the way.

Here is my stylesheet code:

```
.menubox{
    width: 45%;
    height: 13%;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px white;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: fixed;
    float: center;
}
```

And here is my html code:

```
<div class="menubox">

    <table align="center" class="menu">
        <tr>
            <td><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a></td>
            <td><a class="menu" href="about.html">About</a></td>
            <td><a class="menu" href="buy.html">Buy</a></td>
            <td><a class="menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

And here is what it looks like on my webpage:

[My box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHElm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float:center` does not exist and `margin:auto` will not work on a fixed position element.

Since the width of the element is known we can calculate the margins:

```
.menubox {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 27.5%;     /* 55% divided by 2 */
  position: fixed;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.menubox {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 27.5%;
  /* 55%/2 */
  height: 13%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubox">

  <table align="center" class="menu">
    <tr>
      <td><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="about.html">About</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="buy.html">Buy</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Alternatively, rather than doing the calculation (or if the width is not known), you can use a transform.

```
.menubox {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.menubox {
  width: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 13%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubox">

  <table align="center" class="menu">
    <tr>
      <td><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="about.html">About</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="buy.html">Buy</a>
      </td>
      <td><a class="menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position Fixed is relative to the window view

You have to remove from your css the property float:center.
Instead you have to add those two properties

`left:50%;
 margin-left:-22.5%;`

Left:50% property will align your element to the center.
Than you move your element at its negative half to to center it perfectly